# Is there a command-line method for converting UTF-8 values into Unicode values?

Tags: command-line, unicode, utf-8, format-conversion

`$ od -t x1 <inputfile` produces `… 0a e2 8c a5 0a …`.

The `0a` are linefeeds, and `e2 8c a5` are the UTF-8 representation of a Unicode character.

For this simple case, I can do it by hand:

```
[1110]0010  [10]001100  [10]100101  =  10  0011  0010  0101 = 2 3 2 5
```

What shell command line can convert `e2 8c a5` or `e28ca5` into `2325`?

(For completeness, converting the other way would be good to know too.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/147756

Comment: See https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/iconv.1.html

Comment: @Hannu, that question is about Python, not about the command-line shell.

Comment: @FedKad, `echo "e28ca5" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UNICODE` produces `��e28ca5`, not `2325`.  (Actually, it produces `ff fe 65 00 32 00 38 00 63 …`, which looks like UTF-16 for the individual characters.)

Comment: Try `<<<'e28ca5' xxd -r -p | iconv -t unicode | hexdump`; See also the output of `<<<'e28ca5' xxd -r -p`; I get that special character in the gnome-terminal window).

Comment: @RayButterworth and the Python code does exactly what you're asking about, I'd say; learn Python - your will be up running faster than you can believe... Further down, had you read it, `iconv` is mentioned.

Comment: @Hannu, I know Python. I wasn't asking how to do it in Python, I was asking whether there is an existing command-line tool for this, since using existing tools is the Unix philosophy. If you know for sure that there is no such way, post is as an answer and I'll upvote and accept it.  Until then, *you* need to learn to read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command line to get what you want, '2325',

```
$ <<<'e28ca5' xxd -r -p | iconv -t unicode | hexdump
0000000 feff 2325                              
0000004
```

See also the output from the first part of the command line

```
<<<'e28ca5' xxd -r -p
```

(there is no line feed, so the prompt comes directly after its output),

```
sudodus@c30 ~ $ <<<'e28ca5' xxd -r -p
⌥sudodus@c30 ~ $
```

As you can see, I get that special character `⌥` in the gnome-terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Perl [Encode](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode) module, you could

1. pack the character string back into a sequence of bytes<sup>1</sup>
2. *decode* the byte sequence as a UTF-8 character
3. *encode* the result as UTF-16be
4. unpack it to get the hexadecimal code point

So

```
$ printf '%s' 'e28ca5' | perl -MEncode=encode,decode -nE '
    say unpack("H*", encode("UTF-16be", decode("UTF-8", pack("H*",$_))))
'
2325
```

---

1. this step only required because you've unpacked it with `od` - if you start with the character itself or byte sequence you just need the decode-encode:

   ```
    $ printf '⌥' | perl -MEncode=encode,decode -nE '
        say unpack("H*", encode("UTF-16be", decode("UTF-8", $_)))
    '
    2325
   ```

   or

   ```
    $ printf '\xe2\x8c\xa5' | perl -MEncode=encode,decode -nE '
        say unpack("H*", encode("UTF-16be", decode("UTF-8", $_)))
    '
    2325
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ucs2 <inputfile | hexdump -v -e '/2 "%04x "'
```

For `inputfile` containing three bytes with values `e2 8c a5` it outputs `2325`.